# Counting the Words in a String from a file

Tags: c#, string, file-io

I have a small console application that I am working on, and it returns several 0's instead of the actual count of words. I have also noticed in some regards that my logic will be flawed since I am counting spaces. This will not usually count the last word in the string. Any suggestions on how to fix my code. Thanks.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        bool fileExists = false;

        string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string file = filePath + @"\wordcount.txt";

        fileExists = File.Exists(file);

        if (fileExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} contains the following", file);
            Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllLines(file));

            foreach (char words in file)
            {
                int stringCount = 0;
                if (words == ' ')
                {
                    stringCount++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(stringCount);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file does not exist, creating it");
            File.Create(file);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I have edited it so that I am checking the contents instead of the file path (noob here making noob mistakes). I still feel as though my logic with the if statement inside of the foreach loop is bad though.

```
        if (fileExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} contains the following", file);
            string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines(file);

            foreach (string words in contents)
            {
                int stringCount = 0;
                if (words == " ")
                {
                    stringCount++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(stringCount);
            }

        }
```

Comment: You should read the documentation for [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) (there is sample code there as well).

Comment: you're foreach is against 'file' which is the file path.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code I don't know where to start!

Comment: Does it have to do with closing the file before the foreach loop runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) are the function you should look at.

```
var count = File.ReadAllText(file).Split(' ').Count();
```

Comment: I used this with a combination of what I already wrote and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're not reading the actual file, you're reading the `file` variable which you've declared as `filePath + @"\wordcount.txt";`.

You're just outputting the file content to the console. You should assign the result from `File.ReadAllLines(file)` to a new variable (of type `string[]`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) and then run through that.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the file contents to a string you can use this code to count the spaces. The you only need to add 1 to that count to handle the last word.

```
int count = strFileContents.Split(' ').Length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string split

```
 if (fileExists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} contains the following", file);
            Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllLines(file));
            var fileContent=File.ReadAllText();

           stringCount=fileContent.Split(new [] {' ','\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (fileExists)
    {
        string fileString = File.ReadAllText(file);
        var words = fileString.Split(' ');
        int strCount = words.Count();
    }
```

read the file to a string, split it by spaces, count the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this should meet your formatting:

```
List<string> allWords = new List<string>();
foreach (string words in file)
    {
      allWords += words;
    }

int wordCount = allWords.Length();
```

Although, I think @AlexeiLevenkov is better still...

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(file), @"[\S]+").Count;
```